# Sql query to retrieve both side

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Let say I have the following database table

```
Id = int
Source = nvarchar(1)
Destination = nvarchar(1)
```

Basically that represent relation

```
Source -> Destination
Destination -> Source
```

Both relation can exists or only one of them and I want a row that can represent that and I'm not able to find with what kind of SQL join I can achieve that.

I'm trying to write a SQL query that will return the result of both side.
In all examples I want to retrieve info for "A"

If the table have

```
Id = 0
Source = "A"
Destination = "B"
```

I would like to have the following row

```
FirstId = 0, SecondId = NULL
```

If the table have

```
Id = 1
Source = "B"
Destination = "A"
```

I would like to have the following row

```
FirstId = NULL, SecondId = 1
```

If the table have

```
Id = 0
Source = "A"
Destination = "B"
Id = 1
Source = "B"
Destination = "A"
```

I would like to have the following row

```
FirstId = 0, SecondId = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would try a full outer join on the table itself:

```
SELECT A.ID SRCID, B.ID DESTID
FROM TBL A FULL OUTER JOIN TBL B ON A.SOURCE=B.DESTINATION AND B.SOURCE=A.DESTINATION AND A.ID<>B.ID AND (B.DESTINATION='A' OR B.SOURCE='A')
WHERE NVL(A.SOURCE, 'A')='A' OR NVL(A.DESTINATION, 'A')='A'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use aggregation:

```
select max(case when source = 'A' then id end) as a_id,
       max(case when source = 'B' then id end) as b_id       
from t
where source in ('A', 'B') and
      destination in ('A', 'B');
```